# How to get elements with class "a b" and change it to "a" only?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="a b"></div>
```

Say, I want to change it to:

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

And reversely, how to add class "b" to a `div` with class "a"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.a.b').removeClass('b');
```

Answer (score 6):

To remove it:

```
$(".a.b").removeClass("b");
```

To add it:

```
$(".a").addClass("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

To change "a b" to just "a":

```
$('.a.b').removeClass('b');
```

To add class "b" to divs with class "a":

```
$('.a').addClass('b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your first question:

```
$('div').filter('.a, .b').removeClass('b');
```

and this for your second question:

```
$('div.a').addClass('b');
```